# A function that ouputs that highest frequency number

Tags: matlab

The function should give me the highest frequency in an array. For example, if the given vector is:

```
x = [1 2 3 4 4 3 3 3 2 2]
```

The function should return number `3` but it gives me syntax error.

```
function y = frequency(x)
count = 1;
tmpCount=0;
popular = x(1);
tmp = 0;
for i =1:length(x)
    tmp = x(i);
    tmpCount=0;
    for i=2:length(x)
        if (tmp == x(j))
            tempCount++;
        end
        if (tmpCount > count)
            popular = tmp;
            count = tmpCount;
        end
    end
    y=popular; 
end
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing (end) for the first (if) statement? And why do you start the inner (for) from 2?

Comment: no if it's only a one line of code it's fine to not use end

Comment: But how can the compiler tell that the (end) after the first (if) belongs to the (if) or to the (for) statement?

Comment: the other mistake is that you have used `i` as the iteration variable for the inner loop as well as the outer loop when in fact you should be using `j` for the inner one

Comment: @MohamedHeshamIbrahim: You do need an `end` for every `if` statement. The only time an `end` is optional is when ending a function in an m-file when it is the only function. In your code, what you think is the `end` for the function is actually the `end` for your first loop.

Comment: In fact I would recommend using `ii` and `jj` instead of `i` and `j` to separate them from the complex numbers

Comment: You cannot increment with `++` in MATLAB.

Comment: As an aside, you can do this in a couple lines with [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) or something similar.

Comment: thank you guys but it still not working for me

Comment: you can use the matlab function `y=mode(x);`

Comment: can anybody please try to fix it and post it i guess i'm getting confused here

Comment: What language have you written the "draft" code in? It sure isn't Matlab... hence the syntax errors!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Maybe this code groups all the above comments:

```
function y = frequency(x)
  count = 0;
  tmpCount=0;
  popular = x(1);
  tmp = 0;
  for ii =1:length(x)
      tmp = x(ii);
      tmpCount=0;
      for jj=1:length(x)
         if (tmp == x(jj))
            tempCount=tempCount+1;
         end
      end
      if (tmpCount > count)
         popular = tmp;
         count = tmpCount;
      end
   end
   y=popular;

end
```

Comment: thank you but actually it tells me that 'x' is undefined sorry i'm a beginner

Comment: @Mohamed: `x` is your input vector, it's a function of `x`. @Ahmad: No, this doesn't group all the comments and still isn't valid Matlab syntax (for instance `++` would cause an error). This should not be an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in function mode()

Comment: i can't use build-in functions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're looking for a general answer to your question or to a specific fix to your code, but in case of the former, there is a Matlab function called [`mode`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mode.html) that seems to do exactly what you're after, returning the "Most frequent values in array".

```
y=mode(x);
```

Since it's not a built-in function, you can enter `open mode` in your command window and see how it's implemented. One thing to notice is that they don't use any for or while loops. It's best to avoid these wherever possible in Matlab. Also be warry of all the if statements, which are there to generalize the function (e.g. to matrix entries) and make it more fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

**Shortest answer**

Use the `mode` function. `n = mode(x)` returns the highest frequency value in `x`, as you would expect from the definition of the mode!

---

**Your function**

You function has many syntax errors, most of which have already been mentioned in the question comments. Key ones:

- Must have an `end` for *every* `if` in Matlab.
- Cannot use the same loop variable within nested loops (you have with `i`).
- The increment operator `++` doesn't exist in Matlab.

Your function also doesn't account for a tie, where different values have the same frequency. That's a problem for another time!

---

**Corrected code**

See comments for details

```
function popular = frequency(x)
    count = -1;  % Start at -1, nothing been counted yet so at least first element will succeeed
    % Good not to use i or j, as they are the the imaginary constant sqrt(-1)
    % by default, instead use ii, jj
    for ii = 1:length(x) 
        tmp = x(ii);
        tmpCount=0;
        % Ensure nested loop variable is not also ii
        for jj = 1:length(x)
            % Start loop from 1st element, also check not counting itself (when ii=jj)
            if (tmp == x(jj) && ii ~= jj) 
                tmpCount = tmpCount + 1; % MATLAB doesn't support ++
            end
        end
        % Check if new highest freqency
        if (tmpCount > count)
            popular = tmp;
            count = tmpCount;
        end
    end
end
```

---

**Usage**

You said in a comment your `x` was undefined. You probably tried to run this function without an input... In the command window, type

```
x = [1 2 3 4 4 3 3 3 2 2];
frequency(x) % returns 3 as desired
```

---

**Improvement**

In the comments you mysteriously said you can't use built-ins (like `mode`), but if you're allowed an *even more* basic one (`sum`) then this is a streamlined version:

```
function popular = frequency(x)
    count = -1;  % Start at -1, nothing been counted yet so at least first element will succeeed
    % Loop over elements
    for ii = 1:length(x)
        % Get the number of elements with the same value as x(ii)
       tmpCount = sum(x == x(ii));
       if tmpCount > count
           popular = x(ii);
           count = tmpCount;
       end
    end
end
```